# Auto-correcting an inputted String value, in java

Tags: java, hashmap, key, autocorrect

I have a simple application that asks the user for a search term, and then performs a search for that term.

I want to give it the ability to "auto correct" the entered term. This is just for a few terms, that are easy to enter incorrectly. For example, if someone searches for "BestBuy", and what I have in my array to be searched is "Best Buy", I want to automatically convert "BestBuy" into "Best Buy" before the search. I intend to have a list of these in a text file.

What's the best way to do this? Can I have in my text file, every line be something like `bestbuy, Best Buy` the first item being the entered term and the second one being what it gets autocorrected into? What should I use to store this data? A hashmap?

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm not trying to make an actual auto-correct system. That's way, way beyond the scope of this project. This is just to simply replace certain inputs with "corrected" versions to match what is in the array being searched.

Comment: how many terms do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Autocorrect, generally has a harder solution than a hashmap, because you cannot predict the user input, so no point of making a hashmap, though you can use it as a key-existence store.
One possible way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance with the words you have in your map/dictionary, and then selecting the nearest

Answer (score 0):

you could use `HashMap`, create a method that translate all different types of input into the correct one. You method takes input like `bestbuy`, `best buy`, `BestBuy`,etc and return only `Best Buy`. The result `Best Buy` will be the `HashMap` key.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit tricky. To give a high level idea, you need to maintain a hashMap, with string without spaces as `key`, and the corrected value as `value`. when user enters a string, `trim()` it, check with your map' `keyset`, and replace with value if found matching entry.